# Xcode 5 - Check User Has Internet Connection - Incorrect NSStringEncoding Value 0x0000 detected

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have code to be able to detect when the user doesn't have internet that works perfectly BUT every time its triggered a message in the Debug Area appears saying:

> Incorrect NSStringEncoding Value 0x0000 detected. Assuming NSASCIIStringEncoding. Will stop this compatibility mapping in the near future.

How do I get rid of this message?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
NSString *connect = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.co.uk"] encoding:NO error:nil];

if (connect == NULL) { 
//When there isn't internet
}
else {
//When there is
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method called in this line:

```
NSString *connect = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.co.uk"] encoding:NO error:nil];
```

Expect a encoding method for the string, not a BOOL.

Try this:

```
   NSString *connect = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.co.uk"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `NO`(data type `BOOL`) as encoding parameter which is of type `NSStringEncoding`.

The method signature is,

```
+ (instancetype)stringWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url usedEncoding:(NSStringEncoding *)enc error:(NSError **)error
```

Encoding should be one of these,

```
enum {
   NSASCIIStringEncoding = 1,
   NSNEXTSTEPStringEncoding = 2,
   NSJapaneseEUCStringEncoding = 3,
   NSUTF8StringEncoding = 4,
   NSISOLatin1StringEncoding = 5,
   NSSymbolStringEncoding = 6,
   NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding = 7,
   NSShiftJISStringEncoding = 8,
   NSISOLatin2StringEncoding = 9,
   NSUnicodeStringEncoding = 10,
   NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding = 11,
   NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding = 12,
   NSWindowsCP1253StringEncoding = 13,
   NSWindowsCP1254StringEncoding = 14,
   NSWindowsCP1250StringEncoding = 15,
   NSISO2022JPStringEncoding = 21,
   NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding = 30,
   NSUTF16StringEncoding = NSUnicodeStringEncoding,
   NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding = 0x90000100,
   NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding = 0x94000100,
   NSUTF32StringEncoding = 0x8c000100,
   NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding = 0x98000100,
   NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding = 0x9c000100,
   NSProprietaryStringEncoding = 65536
};
```

Ex:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *connect = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.co.uk"] 
                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                              error:&error];
if(error!=nil) {
    //Some error occured
}
```